# Change arrow color based on cell value?

Tags: excel, if-statement, colors, vba

I'm working on a school project and would like to overlay arrows on top on an image to describe traffic flow. If there's little traffic ("A1" < 20) I'd like the arrow to appear green. Other wise I'd like the arrow to change to the color red. I've tried using the if-then-else statement in my VBA code, but keep getting a compile error that's driving me nuts. This is what I have so far:

```
Sub DetermineArrowColor()
Dim ncars As Double

Range("A1").Value = ncars
   If ncars < 20 Then
  'change arrow color to green
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Down Arrow 1")).Select
   With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80) 
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
Else
  'change arrow color to something else
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Down Arrow 1")).Select
   With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 30, 30) 'whatever the numbers are for the color red
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you specify where you get compile error, and what compile error is it?

Comment: I didn't look any closer, but I see you're missing the `End With` statements...

Comment: I'm no expert on this but I seem to recall there is something called `conditional formatting` that lets you colour stuff according to its value - try Googling it.

Comment: @JohnBustos nice catch, that's clearly the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you don't specify which compile error you are getting, but as John Bustos mentioned you are missing `End With`.

Here is an update to your code.

```
Sub DetermineArrowColor()
    Dim ncars As Double

    ncars = Range("A1").Value
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Down Arrow 1")).ShapeRange.Fill
        If ncars < 20 Then
        'change arrow color to green
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        Else
            'change arrow color to something else
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 30, 30)    'whatever the numbers are for the color red
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: He also defines `ncars` backwards

Comment: @Chrismas007 good catch. I couldn't figure out what the OP was doing there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced the other answer works so offer a slight variation:

```
Sub ArrowColour()
Dim ncars As Integer
ncars = Range("A1").Value
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Down Arrow 1")).Fill
        If ncars < 20 Then
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        Else
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```